# can a scala match statement mach something which is not listed in any case? without the underscore?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

for a scala match syntax like this

```
something match {
     case "oneThing" => doOneThing()
     case "anotherThing" => doAnotherThing()
}
```

now point to be considered here is there is no wild card used so clearly for a value of

something = "yetAnotherThing"

there must be nothing executed from any of the cases, if i'm thinking correctly. or there is something i am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `something = "yetAnotherThing"`, the code will cause a `MatchError` exception.